# Specific Questions Regarding Use of Regulated Switching Supplies

Tags: power-supply, safety

For a project I am working on, I have 3 regulated switching supplies, 5v 5a, 12v 5a, 24v 2a. They are the standard, passively-cooled type which look like this[image]

My question:
Can I stack these/have them making contact with each other? I have a very small space to work within, and don't want to screw anything up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chassis *should* be connected to the earth ground terminal (see the datasheet to verify this). As long as they are all connected to the same earth ground and there is plenty of access by air for cooling (or if a fan is added in order to augment cooling and there is still enough airflow through them) there should be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Electrically there should be no problem.  The chassis are usually connected to the ground of the AC input, which would make them all the same and floating with respect to the outputs.

However, this is asking for trouble due to overheating.  The holes you see are to let air flow thru.  By blocking the expected air flow, you will likely only be able to use the supplies at a fraction of their rated power.  Look carefully at the datasheets, and they should tell you how to derate at various temperatures and how much air movement must be allowed.  If you can see that there is a reasonable path for air thru each power supply, like side to side, when the top and bottoms are blocked off, you can probably use forced air to compensate.

You need to study the datasheets carefully, and possibly talk to apps engineers from the power supply companies.